# sscanf - get nth word in a sentence

Tags: c, string, stdin, scanf

I'm new to C, and I'm trying to scan a line from stdin and extract the nth word from it.
Right now I've hard-coded it where you can store the first, second, or third entry in the sentence, and this is what it looks like:

```
int set_to_nth_word(char* word, char* input, int n)
{
    char word1[20];
    char word2[20];
    char word3[20];
    if(sscanf(input, "%s %s %s", word1, word2, word3) < n)
    {
        printf("You didn't enter enough values\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if(n == 1) strcpy(word, word1);
        else if(n == 2) strcpy(word, word2);
        else if(n == 3) strcpy(word, word3);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The code that calls this method is:

```
char *input = (char *) malloc (1);
if(getline(&input, (size_t)0, stdin) != -1)
{
    char word[20];
    if(set_to_nth_word(word, input, 1))
    {
        printf("Success");
    }
}
```

Besides finding a solution to this problem, I'd be happy if anyone points out any bad style or bad coding practices!

Comment: Note that getline() here is a GNU function and is not on all POSIX platforms. (Mac OS X doesn't have it, for example.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of `%n` conversion specifier supported by `sscanf()`.  It requires an `int *` parameter, and returns the number of characters consumed from the input into that `int`.

```
int set_to_nth_word(char *word, const char *input, int n)
{
    int chars_used;

    word[0] = '\0';    /* In case n < 1 */

    while (n > 0 && sscanf(input, "%s%n", word, &chars_used) > 0)
    {
        input += chars_used;
        n--;
    }

    if (n > 0)
    {
        printf("You didn't enter enough values\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

As far as style goes, you should make the `input` parameter `const char *`, since the characters pointed to are not being modified in the function.

In terms of safety, `word` should be allocated with a length of `strlen(input) + 1`, rather than declared as a fixed-size array, since the words may be up to that length.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few pieces of advice:

- instead of scanning a fixed number of words, loop `n` times scanning a single word
- use `strtok` instead of `sscanf` for this; it will make your life much easier
- try to avoid compiled-in limits on how long a word can be (20), especially when you're not checking to see if those limits are being exceeded
- avoid copying string data unnecessarily when scanning it, especially (as stated above) when you're not enforcing length limits on your strcpy calls. Using `strtok` will locate words within the input with zero copies.

Answer (score 0):

Homework?  As homework assignments go, it's a bit interesting, as it tempts one to implement a crude and limited solution yet allows a fairly easy true solution.

Anyway, here is my shot at it...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int set_to_nth_word(char *word, const char *input, int n) {
  int i;
  size_t used = 0;
  char convert[1000];
  static const char convertPattern[] = " %*s";
  static const char convertReal[] = " %s";

  if((unsigned)n > sizeof convert / sizeof convertPattern - 1) 
    return 0;
  for(i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    used += sprintf(convert + used, "%s", convertPattern);
  sprintf(convert + used, "%s", convertReal);
  return sscanf(input, convert, word) == 1;
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  static char space[1000];
  static char wordn[1000];

  if (ac > 1) {
    fgets(space, sizeof space, stdin);
    if(set_to_nth_word(wordn, space, atoi(av[1])))
      printf("%s\n", wordn);
  }
  return 0;
}
```